# Shuffling associate arrays - shuffle doesn't appear to be working

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle the outer array of an associative array (inner arrays should keep same key/value association) but it doesn't appear to be shuffling.

Example:

```
$moo = array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 'val0',
        1 => 'val1',
        2 => 'val2',
        3 => 'val3'
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 'val0',
        1 => 'val1',
        2 => 'val2',
        3 => 'val3'
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => 'val0',
        1 => 'val1',
        2 => 'val2',
        3 => 'val3'
    ),
    3 => array (
        0 => 'val0',
        1 => 'val1',
        2 => 'val2',
        3 => 'val3'
    ),
    4 => array (
        0 => 'val0',
        1 => 'val1',
        2 => 'val2',
        3 => 'val3'
    )
);

shuffle($moo);

print_r($moo);
```

When it is output it's always the same.

Comment: *Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys.* - I'm not sure what you expect, but since all your inner arrays are identical, the result will appear unchanged...

Comment: write something yourself maybe using array_rand for example. Example function here: http://www.webstutorial.com/php-multidimensional-array-shuffle/programming/php. Not a very good one but it gets you started :)

Comment: @deceze Sorry I misunderstood it - I thought it was going to put the key `2` first or something; but I get how it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in right side..Please change the array values and try , then you ca find the difference..

```
$moo = array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 'val0',
        1 => 'val1',
        2 => 'val2',
        3 => 'val3'
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 'cal0',
        1 => 'cal1',
        2 => 'cal2',
        3 => 'cal3'
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => 'ral0',
        1 => 'ral1',
        2 => 'ral2',
        3 => 'ral3'
    ),
    3 => array (
        0 => 'yal0',
        1 => 'yal1',
        2 => 'yal2',
        3 => 'yal3'
    ),
    4 => array (
        0 => 'kal0',
        1 => 'kal1',
        2 => 'kal2',
        3 => 'kal3'
    )
);

shuffle($moo);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($moo);
```

Answer (score 0):

As all 4 inner arrays are the same, how do you recognize whether they are shuffled or not? i.e. shuffling (1,1,1,1) does not make sense in the same way.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @KevinOpdenKamp: why? This is a good, complete answer. It's not spoon-feeding, but tells the whole problem - the arrays get shuffled, but it's hard to tell, because they are all the same. The question's author seems to thing that there are two kinds of arrays in PHP ("associative" and "ordinary"), and he is wrong about it. But you cannot teach everyone everything about PHP in each answer you write.

Comment: I highly doubt it. The OP is trying to shuffle an ASSOCIATIVE array, which is not possible using shuffle and keeping all of the original keys in the first place. php.net: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys. He's just using some example data, of course he knows it wouldn't make sense to shuffle values if they're all the same...that's what I'm hoping at least!

Comment: Yes, we can only guess what OP intends to do. As far as what he posted, I think the best answer is say it the simplest way and if it isn't enough, let op provide more information on what he intends to do.